# How to split python dataframe rows in one to one mapping form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm trying to split python dataframe rows to one to one mapping format such that each new line represents the value in the same order as the column in front and if there is a single value on other columns copy their value in the new created row, like:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| valueA1 | valueB1 valueB2 valueB3 | valueC1 valueC2 valueC3 |
| valueA2 | valueB4 | valueC4 |

Should split like:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| valueA1 | valueB1 | valueC1 |
| valueA1 | valueB2 | valueC2 |
| valueA1 | valueB3 | valueC3 |
| valueA2 | valueB4 | valueC4 |

Here all values are string type.

I did tried `explode()` but that was not splitting in one to one format, any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Are the values in DataFrame strings with newlines or list or strings?

Comment: They are string type, all entries are object type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution only focuses on columns `B` and `C`:

```
df1[['B', 'C']] = df1[['B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\n'))
df1 = df1.explode(list('BC'))
df1
         A        B        C
0  valueA1  valueB1  valueC1
0  valueA1  valueB2  valueC2
0  valueA1  valueB3  valueC3
1  valueA2  valueB4  valueC4
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn your columns to lists by splitting the lines and then explode them

```py
In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
         A                          B                          C
0  valueA1  ValueB1\nValueB2\nValueB3  ValueC1\nValueC2\nValueC3
1  valueA2                    ValueB4                    ValueC4

In [29]: df.apply(lambda col: col.str.split()).explode("A").explode(["B", "C"])
Out[29]: 
         A        B        C
0  valueA1  ValueB1  ValueC1
0  valueA1  ValueB2  ValueC2
0  valueA1  ValueB3  ValueC3
1  valueA2  ValueB4  ValueC4
```